# Silverlight: Creating a DataTemplate in XAML, and assigning it in code?

Tags: c#, silverlight, xaml

Is it possible to create a DataTemplate in XAML, and apply it to various controls via code?

If so, how do I reference a DataTemplate that I've built in XAML?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

if you have

```
   <UserControl.Resources>
       <DataTemplate x:Name="myTemplate" />
   </UserControl.Resources>
```

defined as a resource, you can reference it like this

```
var myTemplate  = (DataTemplate) Resources["myTemplate"];
```

Comment: Where is the "Resources" type located? I'd like to use it in a converter class.

Comment: `Resources` is from `FrameworkElement` but in this case it is from the UserControl.

Comment: put that resource in App.xaml
<Application.Resources>
    <DataTemplate x:Key="myTemplate"/>
</Application.Resources>

to use it type Application.Recources[] anywhere.