# Define a DataTemplate in XAML?

Tags: xamarin, xamarin.forms

Is it possible to define a DataTemplate in a XAML file and use it in code?

According to this answer:
[Silverlight: Creating a DataTemplate in XAML, and assigning it in code?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5530959/silverlight-creating-a-datatemplate-in-xaml-and-assigning-it-in-code)

I can define it and add it to Resources dictionary in App.xaml, but I don't have an App.xaml file in my PCL project.

It sounds like a trivial thing, there has to be a standard way to do this.

You can find an example of a DataTemplate [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/ask)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Yes, it's nearly the same only `x:Key` instead of `x:Name`.

```xml
<ContentPage.Resources>
    <ResourceDictionary>
      <DataTemplate x:Key="myTemplate"></DataTemplate>
    </ResourceDictionary>
</ContentPage.Resources>
```

and in your code in your Page:

```cs
var myTemplate = (DataTemplate)Resources["myTemplate"];
```

If you want to define it in your App.xaml, you can do that too. You have to create the file manually. Have a look at the sample https://github.com/xamarin/xamarin-forms-samples/tree/master/WorkingWithStyles

To create the App.xaml:

- create a file App.xaml
- add `partial` to the class definition of App in `App.cs`
- call `InitializeComponent()` in the constructor of `App`
- go to Properties of App.xaml and set

  - Build Action: Embedded Resource
  - Custom Tool: MSBuild:UpdateDesignTimeXaml

It should look like this:

**App.xaml**

```xml
<Application
    xmlns="http://xamarin.com/schemas/2014/forms"
    xmlns:x="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2009/xaml"
    x:Class="App6.App">
    <Application.Resources>
        <ResourceDictionary>
            <DataTemplate x:Key="myTemplate"></DataTemplate>
        </ResourceDictionary>
    </Application.Resources>
</Application>
```

**App.cs**

```cs
public partial class App : Application
{
    public App()
    {
        InitializeComponent();
        var myTemplate = (DataTemplate)Resources["myTemplate"];
        MainPage = new Page2();
    }

    protected override void OnStart()
    {
        // Handle when your app starts
    }

    protected override void OnSleep()
    {
        // Handle when your app sleeps
    }

    protected override void OnResume()
    {
        // Handle when your app resumes
    }
}
```

Comment: There's no way to define it as a standalone class instead of a resource in a page or the app?

Comment: You mean something like `class MyDataTemplate : DataTemplate` ??

Comment: I was replying to someone else. Read the first comment.